# why any build of chromium for android crash on runtime?

Tags: android, google-chrome, build, crash, chromium

I want to build chromium for android and did every instructions on this [page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/android_build_instructions.md).

the commands used to build chromium:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"
mkdir ~/chromium && cd ~/chromium
fetch --nohooks android
cd src
echo "target_os = [ 'android' ]" >> ../.gclient
gclient sync -D --force
gn args out/Default
autoninja -C out/Default monochrome_public_bundle
```

When I set the arg `is_debug` to true every things works fine but when I set this to false the built `apk` crashes in 2 seconds after opening the app.
Here is the used args for building the `apk`:

```
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm"  

is_debug = false
symbol_level = 1
```

these arguments works for version 107 but crashes in newer versions. I have tried different versions of chromium from 109 to 115 and tested on different versions of android 10, 11, 12, 13 but chromium keeps crashing.

error logs:

```
Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{e2e9dfb u0 org.chromium.chrome.stable/org.chromium.chrome.browser.firstrun.FirstRunActivity EXITING}
android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:646)
at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:551)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:4374)
at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$5$com-android-server-wm-InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:348)
at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:2)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:357)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:238)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$new$1$com-android-server-wm-WindowAnimator(WindowAnimator.java:109)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.doFrame(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1384)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1394)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1013)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:904)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1366)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
shouldWaitAnimatingExit: isAnimating: Window{e2e9dfb u0 org.chromium.chrome.stable/org.chromium.chrome.browser.firstrun.FirstRunActivity EXITING}
Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{e2e9dfb u0 org.chromium.chrome.stable/org.chromium.chrome.browser.firstrun.FirstRunActivity EXITING}
android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:646)
at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchAppVisibility(IWindow.java:614)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowState.java:3772)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowContainer.java:1290)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible(WindowToken.java:419)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible(ActivityRecord.java:7277)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished(ActivityRecord.java:8152)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation(ActivityRecord.java:5888)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:5860)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:5864)
at com.android.server.wm.AppTransitionController.handleClosingApps(AppTransitionController.java:1196)
at com.android.server.wm.AppTransitionController.handleAppTransitionReady(AppTransitionController.java:295)
at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.checkAppTransitionReady(RootWindowContainer.java:1028)
at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace(RootWindowContainer.java:895)
at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement(RootWindowContainer.java:835)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:199)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:148)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:137)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer$Traverser.run(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:79)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

what should I do?

Comment: Splitting a Q up between two websites and pointing each to the other for more info is a terrible idea. Minor differences between the two also adds unnecessary complexity for those trying to weave it back together.